# SSL Not Working On Subdomain Prefix With (+WWW)

Tags: ssl, http, domain, https, subdomain

I couldn't find the exact solution here. I'm using Hostgator hosting.

[image: Cpanel Screenshot]

Comment: How did you obtain the SSL certificate, and what domain names did you list when obtaining it?

Comment: I have added SSL by browsing the certificate of the main domain into the subdomain. It is working on <---https://something.edu.in---> but not working on <---www.something.edu.in--->.

Comment: A certificate has the domain stored inside the certificate. If you have not used the proper way to install a certificate, it won't work. You need to either buy a certificate specifically for this subdomain, or you must use a free provider to create and install a new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are issued or configured per subdomain, unless they are specifically told be a wildcard certificate.

So a certificate for **www.example.com** will not work for **example.com**, nor for **test.example.com**

If you want the certificate to work for any subdomain, including www, you'd need to issue one for ***.example.com**